# Error while Copying CSV File in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv-import

my query:

```
COPY public.project from $$C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\adbviz\projects_export.csv$$ DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

and here is the error:

> ERROR:  could not open file
>   "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\adbviz\projects_export.csv" for reading:
>   Permission denied

guide me to solve this problem

Comment: Postgres can't access that file, as it comes from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error Message is clearly saying that it doesn't have *permission for reading that csv file*

Store `projects_export.csv` another location on your system (For example `D` Drive ) file then it will work,i.e

```
   COPY public.project from 'D:\Folder\projects_export.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```